# Need a single term for a set of sleeping people

Tags: single-word-requests

Can I write 'Do not wake the asleep'?  Or does it have to be 'Do not wake the sleeping'?  I am looking for a single term for a set of sleeping people.

Comment: A group of sleeping people are usually called 'sleepers'.

Comment: I thought I saw a very similar question recently. This might be a duplicate.

Comment: Certainly not *Do not wake the asleep.* It may just be grammatical, but it's unidiomatic (here in the UK at least).

Comment: Hi KillingTime, somehow 'sleepers' does not give a sense of the immediate.  Writing 'Do now wake the sleepers' gives a different feel than 'Do not wake those who are sleeping'?  At least to my ears they feel different enough.  It is the latter that I am striving to make more concise.  I suppose I will have to settle for 'Do not wake those who are asleep'.  Replacing 'those who are' or 'those that are' with just 'the' is proving difficult.

Comment: Thanks, High Performance Mark.  Not surprising.  It sounds a bit off.

Comment: Let sleeping people lie.   Quiet! People [are] sleeping.

Answer (score 1):

*Sleeping* is not out of the question:

> *Do not wake the sleeping.*

*Sleeping* is an example of—in traditional grammar terms—a nominalized adjective or an adjectival noun. It's an adjective—in this case a present participle adjective—functioning as a noun:

> . . . an adjective that has undergone nominalization, and is thus used
>   as a noun. In *the rich and the poor*, the adjectives *rich* *and
>   poor* function as nouns denoting people who are rich and poor
>   respectively. . . . The most common appearance of the nominalized
>   adjective in English is when an adjective is used to indicate a
>   collective group. This happens in the case where a phrase such as *the
>   poor people* becomes *the poor*. The adjective *poor* is nominalized,
>   and the noun *people* disappears.
>
> <sub>Source: Wikipedia [Nominalized
>   adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective). See
>   also: [Annotated Bibliography : B1 Adjectival
>   Nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Nominalized_adjective#Annotated_Bibliography_:_B1_Adjectival_Nouns)</sub>

---

*CGEL*—in its chapter titled *Nouns and noun phrases*—classes this form as one of several types of a "fusion of internal modifier and head":

> (f) **Modifier-heads with special interpretations**
>
> ```
> [29] i   [The French] do these differently from [the Dutch].
>      ii  [The rich] cannot enter the kingdom of Heaven.
>      iii How will the new system affect [the very poor]?
>      iv  We are going to attempt [the utterly impossible].
>      v   This is verging on [the immoral].
>      vi  They like to swim in [the nude].
> ```
>
> A rather restricted range of adjectives . . . occur in fused-head
>   constructions with special interpretations. The NPs are determined by
>   the definite article – we couldn’t even substitute a demonstrative:
>   **these very poor*. Examples [i–iii] illustrate a subtype denoting categories of human being; these NPs are characteristically used
>   generically, as here. . . . NPs like those in [ii–iii] can be
>   paraphrased by means of *those* + relative clause: *those who are rich
>   /very poor*. This subtype includes adjectives based on past participle
>   forms or similar denominal derivatives in ·*ed*: *the disadvantaged*,
>   *the intellectually gifted*, *the unemployed*, *the hard-hearted*, and so on.
>
> <sub>Source: *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, Ch. 5
>   §9.3 (f)</sub>

---

Note that CGEL does not mention adjectives based on present participle forms here, and it's true that it is unusual to use a present participle adjective in this manner. But COCA turns up a good number of examples, including *the dying* and *the missing*. And you will not be entirely alone if you use *the sleeping*; COCA returns four or five relevant examples:

[image: COCA screenshot for THE SLEEPING . results]

<sub>Source: [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=84495224) (click THE SLEEPING . to expand)</sub>

---

If using *sleeping* as a noun for a collective group still bothers you, you can try a relative clause:

> *Do not wake those who are sleeping.*

Then you can reduce the relative clause:

> *Do not wake those sleeping.*

That gains you little if nothing, though.

---

Lastly, why can't we nominalize the adjective *asleep* as we did *sleeping*? *Asleep* is a predicative-only adjective; it can't be use attributively (in front of a noun). We can say *the people are asleep*, but we can't say *the asleep people*. We can turn *sleeping people* into *the sleeping* by dropping the noun following the attributive *sleeping*. But there is no attributive *asleep*, so there is no noun following it to drop.