# The number of (the) unemployed/super-rich/poor/dead/infected

Tags: nouns, adjectives, articles, definite-articles, zero-article

'*The* + adjective' usually means 'adjective + *people*'. For example, *the unemployed* means 'unemployed people'. In this type of construction, you cannot remove *the*.

But when the construction is positioned after 'the number of', the necessity of *the* changes.

For example,

> *the number of unemployed is...*

is not only possible without *the* but even sounds better than

> *the number of **the** unemployed is...*.

This is counterintuitive because you normally cannot remove *the* in this type of construction.

And here are similar examples where the version without *the* is possible and even sounds better than the one with *the*:

> The number of (the) super-rich is...
>
> The number of (the) poor is...
>
> The number of (the) dead is...
>
> The number of (the) infected is...

Is there any explanation for this phenomenon?

Comment: Merely nominalisation. It is often inconvenient, and often sounds a little unsophisticated, to use 'the poor people', 'the infected people' .... The adjective is pressed into service, and is apparently being afforded the same grammatical treatment as a regular noun. The number of survivors / injured / dead ....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think _poor_ in _the poor are..._ is merely an instance of nominalization. You can say _the very poor are..._, which shows that _poor_ is still an adjective in the construction. // To be distinguished from cases of the real nominalization such as _He's a common criminal._

Comment: I suppose that "the number of the" requires a quantification, as in: "the number of the dead is 250" vs an evaluation expressed without the article, as in "the number of dead is unbelievable"

Comment: @Nico But The New York Times says, "Worldwide, the number of dead topped 95,000...".

Comment: Are you sure that "the number of" is the only case where "the" would be omitted? Compare: "[The line of unemployed](https://books.google.com/books?id=_xlc5xsN8FwC&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq="the+line+of+unemployed"), " "[the crowd of unemployed](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rocks_in_the_Water_Rocks_in_the_Sun/R1-gBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+crowd+of+unemployed%22&pg=PA268&printsec=frontcover)," "[the throngs of unemployed](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Making_Workers_Soviet/qaFhDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq="the+throngs+of+unemployed")."

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin You're right. They are also possible. I've edited the question.

Comment: *The poor* is what CGEL calls a fused-head NP. And it doesn't mean *the poor people* — it means a class of people who are poor. It seems that when you use *poor* with *the number of*, you no longer have a fused head NP but rather an elliptical construction with *people* left out: *The number of poor [people]* . . . *Poor* is not a class here. See my answer here for possible further clues: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/525444/need-a-single-term-for-a-set-of-sleeping-people/525506

Comment: @TinfoilHat You're right that what comes after _the number of_ denotes not a class but a definite set of people. But here are two things. (1) I think CGEL would analyze it not as ellipsis but as fusion. (2) The class denotation of such adjectives doesn't seem to have much to do with the omission of _the_, since, for example, _the dead_ in _Most of the dead in the U.S. are in New York_--where I don't think you can omit _the_--clearly denotes not a class but a definite set of dead people.

Comment: Depends on context, and you've given none.

Comment: Generally, you add the for specificity. General statements, would not take the: The number of super-rich who don't pay taxes is very high.

Comment: @Lambie Remember, when you say 'the super-rich', you're talking about 'super-rich people in general'.

Comment: If it starts a sentence and is a category, yes. But not in: the number of super-rich. The discussion is about: the or null set **number of** x.

Comment: @Lambie In the construction of 'the number of x', x should mean some specific group since only specific group can be counted: In _The number of people who have survived the virus so far are nowhere near enough to reopen all the shuttered shops and offices_, for example, _people who have survived the virus so far_ are not general people but has to be a specific group of people in order for you to count them. But you don't use _the_ here.

Comment: @JK2, I am not going to do this today.

Comment: @JK2 It depends on which definition of _nominalisation_ you choose.  '[T]hree types of nominalizations can be distinguished: nominalizations at the level of the word (e.g. teacher, Sam's washing of the windows), nominalizations which nominalize a structure that lies in between a verb and a full clause (e.g. Sam's washing the windows) and, finally, nominalizations consisting of full clauses (e.g. that Sam washed the windows). The latter two types deviate from the 'normal' rank scale of units in that they represent nominals or phrases which consist of clausal or clause-like structures....

Comment: They have therefore been regarded as problematic, and it has even be claimed that that-structures are not nominalizations (e.g., Dik 1997; McGregor 1997)." (Liesbet Heyvaert, "A Cognitive-Functional Approach to Nominalization in English".  2003)' [[Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/nominalization-in-grammar-1691430)]. 'Sam's slowly washing the windows was painful to watch' shows that some nominalisations may be considered modifiable by adverbs. Tests fail. (I'm still looking for a 'process' sense definition for 'nominalisation'.

Comment: ... Ah, [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nominalizationhttps:) has: _nominalisation_: the **process** or result of forming a noun or noun phrase from a clause or a verb. Other dictionaries will increase the number of starters (to include adjectives). And processes can be more or less gradual (the conversion of 'fun', say, in the other direction).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Although I'm not really buying the treatment of _the unemployed_ as a type of nominalization, let's say for the sake of argument that it is a type of nominalization. How would that be able to help answer the question?

Comment: Note that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjectival_noun) has: << **Nominalized adjective**: an adjective which has come to function as a noun, as in the rich and the poor >>. _To what extent?_ // Article usage before an unequivocal noun is being mimicked by these whotsits. eg 'The number of French was but small in comparison with the Moors' [[Chalons_The History of France, Etc, Volume 1]https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=o5mP46rexdkC&pg=PA54&dq=%22number+of+french+was%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMmMmDre_oAhUAaRUIHftdCdQQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22number%20of%20french%20was%22&f=false]]

Comment: So I'm claiming a gradual turning-into-an-unarguable-noun. // There's still argument about whether 'steel' in 'steel bridge' has been fully 'adjectivalised' yet. Change is often gradual, and exact positions on a cline hard to pinpoint.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see where you're coming from. But please note that what follows 'the number of' generally refers to a definite group of people whereas 'the + adjective' generally refers to an indefinite group of people. In your example, 'French' (without 'the') refers to a definite group of French people participating in the battle, as opposed to French people in general. Then, how is this anything like "mimicking" unequivocal nouns?

Comment: @JK2 I repeat, 'the number of survivors was horrifyingly low' / 'the number of dead was horrifyingly high' (mirroring OP's examples).

Comment: You can leave out an ellipsis interpretation (*dead [people]*) and just go with the dictionary definition of *dead* at noun: a dead person.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Then, the question becomes why 'survivors' in 'the number of survivors' is without 'the' even though it denotes a definite group of people. And whatever the reason for omitting 'the' in 'the number of survivors' is cannot be the reason for omitting 'the' in 'the number of dead', because 'the' in 'the dead' does not denote definiteness in the first place whereas 'the' in 'the survivors' does.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Then, why is 'the' possible in 'the number of the dead is...', albeit perhaps a bit less natural? (Note that 'the' is impossible in 'the number of the dead people is...'.)

Comment: Just like any other noun . . . The number of cats . . . The number of the cats . . .

Comment: @TinfoilHat No, you're missing my point. Prototypical nouns such as 'survivors' do not allow 'the' after 'the number of'. But 'dead' does allow 'the' after 'the number of'.

Comment: @TinfoilHat In Google News, "the number of cats is" has many hits, whereas "the number of the cats is" has only one hit, which is "Arab News".

Comment: Where are you seeing *the number of the dead is*?

Comment: @TinfoilHat This Economist article, for example, mentions "the number of the dead" twice but no mention of "the number of dead": https://www.economist.com/briefing/2020/02/29/covid-19-is-now-in-50-countries-and-things-will-get-worse

Comment: That *the number* (in both places) is literally a numerator of a math fraction.

Comment: @TinfoilHat So what?

Comment: It's an outside case that complicates whatever it is you're looking for in the way of an explanation for how we use *dead* and *the dead*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Please provide at least some evidence that the noun phrase 'the number of the dead' in The Economist is "an outside case" just because it is used to describe a numerator. Also, are you claiming that the OP's examples are not possible English with 'the'?

Comment: @JK2 I'm sorry, this is a bit out of context, you said we don't use "the survivors" or "the cats" after "of" like in this sentence "The number of the survivors/the cats..." Could I know why is this so? I don't see any grammatical rule that prohibits it or is the use of "the" just unnecessary?

Comment: @English--moreexcthanlaws I think you should ask the question over on ELL.